# Как добавить дополнительный текст в button

Tags: android, текст, android-button

Как можно и можно ли вообще добавить дополнительный текс к кнопке? Допустим один чёрный большой и жирный, а под ним серого цвета и меньшего размера пояснение.

Comment: Button это TextView с бэкграундом в виде кнопки (класс Button наследуется от TextView), с ним можно делать все то же, что и с TextView, соответственно менять текст через Spannable, например или Html.fromHtml(). Более простой вариант, повесить бэкграунд кнопки и слушатель кликов на какой то контейнер, например LinearLayout. В контейнере расположить виджеты TextView с нужными вам размерами текста и цветом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже было замечено в комментариях вам можно отобразить в кнопке html текст. Сам html вы можете настроить так как вам нужно, в вашем случае что-то будет черным и жирным, а что-то серым и меньшего размера. А дальше html отображаем в кнопке:

```
button.setText(Html.fromHtml(\\ здесь размещаем ваш html))
```

Либо есть второй вариант, сделать контейнер у которого будет нужный вам текст, и ловить клики на нем:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/clickLayout"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="test1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="test2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

и далее в активности можно обрабатывать клики по данному layout:

```
LinearLayout linLay = findViewById(R.id.clickLayout);
linLay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Так же текст можно изменить при помощи [Spannable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable). Вот [туториал](https://habr.com/ru/company/tdb/blog/340232/) и вот пример:

```
SpannableString spannablecontent=new SpannableString(o.content.toString());
spannablecontent.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC), 
                         0,spannablecontent.length(), 0);
```

и дальше `button.setText(spannablecontent)` и все.